# HTTP JSON request in JS - CORS issue

Tags: javascript, json, rest, ibm-watson

The goal of this project is to use IBM's Watson and its natural language understanding AI.

When I use Insomnia (a REST client) I can get a POST request to go through and get a JSON response.

However, when I try using javascript I am not able to POST a request and receive the following error:
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at '*WEBSITE-I'M-TRYING-TO-REACH*' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request."

Here is the code I am using:

```js
var url = "http://newsroom.ibm.com/Guerbet-and-IBM-Watson-Health-Announce-Strategic-Partnership-for-Artificial-Intelligence-in-Medical-Imaging-Liver"

getData(url);

function getData(url){
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    "url": url,
    "features": {
      "sentiment": {},
      "categories": {},
      "concepts": {},
      "entities": {},
      "keywords": {}
    }
  });

  var postURL = "https://api.us-south.natural-language-understanding.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/9d2bd18a-8017-4e44-8de9-acc01a9f0795/v1/analyze?version=2019-07-12"

  var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xml.withCredentials = true;

  xml.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  });

  var username = "myUsername";
  var password = "myPassword";
  xml.open("POST", postURL);
  xml.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
  xml.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + username + ":" + password)

  xml.send(data);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>JSON Requests</title>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>JSON Requests</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As said, put the origin key in the header :

`xml.setRequestHeader("Origin", "https://the-great.site");`